# Docker containers with different artificial delays

Tags: docker, docker-network

Let's say there are 2 groups, each having 2 docker containers. Eg: Group-1 (C1 & C2), Group-2 (C3, C4). I want all 4 containers to be in same network but with different latencies. Eg: when C1 & C2 (same group) ping each other, delay should be something like 2ms. But when C1 & C3 (different group) ping each other, delay should be something like 10ms. I can use "tc" to control the artificial network delay for an interface.

**What I have tried:**
Created 1 docker network which is common in all 4 containers (eth0 on all containers have 172.18.0.x IP), & 2 other networks each for a group (eth1 on C1 & C2 have 192.168.54.x IP and eth1 on C3 & C4 have 192.168.55.x IP). Using "tc" command, I set delay for eth0 as 5ms & eth1 as 1ms in each container. But problem with this is that, the service that I want to use shares it's configured IP address with all other nodes. So If I use eth0 IP, C1 & C2 will have more network delay (10ms) even though in same group & desired delay is 2ms. And if I use eth1 IP, C1 & C3 can't communicate.

Can someone please suggest a way to solve this. I am using docker on linux host. I'm doing this to simulate a multi-region network environment.

Comment: this might help you
https://medium.com/@kazushi/simulate-high-latency-network-using-docker-containerand-tc-commands-a3e503ea4307

Comment: Thanks @muhammadshahan but I know how to use "tc" for simulating latencies. The requirement here is different.